# Is prezi file format supported on android and ios

Tags: android, ios, offline, prezi

I would like to know if there are offline available applications to read prezi file format ?

I already saw some people use online link to open these docs:

- [Open prezi from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495853/open-prezi-from-app)

It's not this method that I am looking for.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

There is an OFFICIAL prezi player for iOS, downloadable from iTunes, see e.g. http://prezi.com/ipad/

There is an UNOFFICIAL prezi player for Android, downloadable through links on the following forumpost:
http://community.prezi.com/prezi/topics/final_beta_for_unofficial_prezi_player_for_android

Provided there is no (Youtube) video in your prezi, the prezi will normally be played locally on both iOs as Android (using the OFFICIAL iPad player from Prezi, or the UNOFFICIAL Android player).

Kind regards,

Roel
Disclaimer: I wrote the UNOFFICIAL prezi player app.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one, work like a charm!

http://www.itbox4vn.com/2013/04/how-to-present-prezi-on-android-phone.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.